# ren won't use my variable from one lina above

Tags: cmd

I've got a strange problem. I want to rename multiple files in a folder.
So far, so easy - in theory. I use this script:

```
cd C:\Test

for %%i in (*(7*) do (
    set name="%%i"
    ren "%name%" "%name:~0,-15%.txt"
)

pause
```

The strange thing is that he seems to not use the variable "name" I declared 
one line above the ren command as you can see in what the console prints:

C:\Test>(
set name="ttttt(7xAAdoc) .txt"
 ren "" "~0,-15.txt"
)

What am I missing here? I am running Windows 7, if thats important.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

In your case,

```
cd C:\Test
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*(7*) do (
    set "name=%%i"
    ren "%name%" "!name:~0,-15!.txt"
)
```

note the positioning of the quotes in the first `set`. The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`. As you had it, `name` would be assigned a `"quoted"` value and the `ren` command (had it worked) would have been `ren ""filename"" ""firstpartoffilename".txt"

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, that really helps me understanding the issue.